# Marking dataframe rows based on list

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe consisting of column Group "G" and timestamp "T".
I have a list that is giving me time ranges for a specific group.
`[[a, 2, 4],[a, 5, 6],[b, 2, 4]]`

What I need is column "Need", which is marking the rows that are defined in the ranges of the list.

What is fastest way of achieving this task? Because this job would run on very big data.

```
G   T   Need
------------
a   1   
a   2   True
a   3   True
a   4   
a   5   True
a   6   True
a   7   
b   1   
b   2   True
b   3   True
b   4   True
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Spark dataframe from the list, and do a left join:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

times = [['a', 2, 3], ['a', 5, 6], ['b', 2, 4]]
times_df = spark.createDataFrame(times, ['G', 'T0', 'T1'])

result = df.join(
    times_df,
    (df['G'] == times_df['G']) & 
    df['T'].between(times_df['T0'], times_df['T1']),
    'left'
).select(
    df['*'],
    F.when(times_df['G'].isNotNull(), F.lit(True)).alias('need')
)

result.show()
+---+---+----+
|  G|  T|need|
+---+---+----+
|  b|  1|null|
|  b|  2|true|
|  b|  3|true|
|  b|  4|true|
|  a|  1|null|
|  a|  2|true|
|  a|  3|true|
|  a|  4|null|
|  a|  5|true|
|  a|  6|true|
|  a|  7|null|
+---+---+----+
```